# Install-Package LibUsbDotNet -Version 2.2.18 Attempting to resolve dependency 'LibUsb.Common (≥ 2.2.18)'. I

Tags: c#

> Install-Package : 'LibUsbDotNet' already has a dependency defined for 'LibUsb.Common'.
>   At line:1 char:16
>   + Install-Package <<<<  LibUsbDotNet -Version 2.2.18
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

I got this error when installing the latest LibUsbDotNet version. How can i solve this?

Comment: Which version of nuget are you using?

Comment: Latest Version of NuGet.Core -Version 2.14.0

Comment: My Nuget packages Manager version is 2.8.60318.667

Comment: Please i need help.. Thank you